# Add ViewControllers in a Scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I'm working on a project where I'd like to have a series of user interactive views (created in Interface builder, and have their own implementation and header files), displayed in a single scrollview with paging enabled. I have yet to come across an example which is easy to understand. Could someone provide code which does this?

Here is a schematic of how things should work.[image]

Comment: which ios versions are you targeting?

Comment: Chancy: I'm targeting iOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UIPageViewController` with Scroll style if you are targeting ios 6 or later, which is much easier than `UIScrollView`. And if you search `UIPageViewController` scroll example in google, there are quite lots of samples. The following are two of them:

[Using ScrollStyle with UIPageViewController](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/using-scrollstyle-with-uipageviewcontroller/)

[How to Use UIPageViewController to Build Tutorial Screens](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/)

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: So a pageview controller would allow me to refer to other xibs and display them in one view like the schematic I posted?

Comment: @user2563039, YES, you just init the UIViewController with xibs in the data source of UIPageViewController. That's quite simple.